# I'm using this scrolling bookmark js script, why aren't my target id's lining up?

Tags: jquery

I am using option B on this script: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/bookmarkscroll.htm

My target element doesn't line up with the id. When you click the link it should scroll to the id and display at the top of the page...

```
bookmarkscroll.scrollTo('sectionb')

<a href="javascript:bookmarkscroll.scrollTo('sectionb')">Scroll to Section B</a>
```

I should mention that I am using this for an FAQ page.

the questions (hyperlinks) are single spaced at the top of the page and the answers are about 20 br's down the page.

For this to work, do you need to have a significant amount of page text per answer?

[link to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/stYyvWcv)

Comment: thanks @Armatus. I didn't even notice the Accept check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your page, what seems most likely to me is that below the heading to which you scroll, you don't have enough content (height) to fill the whole screen. So when you scroll down there, the scrollbar reaches the bottom before the heading aligns with the top of the browser window.

Try adding enough paragraphs below that heading to fill the screen and see if that helps.

Comment: As I said, that's exactly the problem I described. Try adding a `<div style="height:600px;">&nbsp;</div>` below each heading.